# How Do I make a div tag occupy the half of the right hand side of my Web page?

Tags: html

It is a basic HTML question.

I have some div tags, which have some controls and occupy left half of my screem.

I Want to have a div tag to display some messages in the right side?
I used somthings like:

```
float = right;
```

in my css class. It didn't seem to work. What other properties I need to set.

Here is the code sample

```
<div class ="header_label">
@Html.GetLocalizedString("program_snapshotRecipientAdress")&nbsp; @Html.TextBox("txtRcpntAdress")
</div>

   <div class ="header_label">
@Html.GetLocalizedString("program_snapshotUsertype1") &nbsp; @Html.RadioButton("Usertype", "One", new { id="rb1"})
 &nbsp; &nbsp;
@Html.GetLocalizedString("program_snapshotUsertype2") &nbsp; @Html.RadioButton("Usertype", "Two", new { id = "rb2" })
<div class ="commentsHeight"></div>
 </div>
   <div class ="header_label">
@Html.GetLocalizedString("program_snapshotDate") &nbsp; @Html.TextBox("SnapshotDate")
</div>

  <div id ="CMSContent">
<div class ="CMS-message">
@Html.Raw("S=This is the div I need to place in the right hand side")
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to add some code to get some help. Don't know if you don't show. You may need absolute positioning though.

Comment: Can you post some more code? Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I didn't understand your question so much, but I'll try to answer.
If you have some div on the left and you want another one on the right you have two choice:

1) The first one is to set one div on the right and another on the left:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%">I'm on the left</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 50%">I'm on the right</div>
</div>
```

2) The second one is to set every div on the left

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%">I'm on the left</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%">I'm on the second on the left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was lookign for. Thanks, it worked.Now I neednt use any css class to render this isnt it. Can u explain the difference between using a style attribute directly and using a class from css file as div class="something" and defining this float and width in "something".

Comment: There isn't a "big difference", using a class is a better solution if you have a site with many pages: if you use only 'style="something"' and you need to change something you have to modify all pages; if you use a class you have to modify only one file ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure that you named the div correctly?
2. the correct way to your command is

   ```
   float : right;
   ```
3. If you want your div to be half of your screen you should write something like:

   ```
   width : 50%;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a div occupy the right hand side of the screen in a multitude of ways, one of which is 'floating' as you've found.

This takes the element out of the normal 'flow' of the document and allows it to occupy a different area of the screen depending on parent elements etc.

At a glance you would need to write:

```
float: right;
```

In your CSS, rather than `=` but if you could post some html and css in a more full form, some better advice can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show your form or something in two halfs or grids use this:
float: right;
width: 50%;